# Can a ReactJS app with a router be hosted on S3 and fronted by an nginx proxy?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3

I may be twisting things about horribly, but...  I was given a ReactJS application that has to be served out to multiple sub-domains, so

```
   a.foo.bar
   b.foo.bar
   c.foo.bar
   ...
```

Each of these should point to a different instance of the application, but I don't want to run `npm start` for each one - that would be a crazy amount of server resources.

So I went to host these on S3.  I have a bucket `foo.bar` and then directories under that for `a` `b` `c`... and set that bucket up to serve static web sites.  So far so good - if I go to https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo.bar/a/ I will get the index page.  However most things tend to break from there as there are non-relative links to things like `/css/` or `/somepath` - those break because they aren't smart enough to realize they're being served from /foo.bar/a/.  Plus we want a domain slapped on this anyway.

So now I need to map `a.foo.bar` -> `https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo.bar/a/`.  We aren't hosting our domain with AWS, so I'm not sure if it's possible to front this with CloudFront or similar.  Open to a solution along those lines, but I couldn't find it.

Instead, I stood up a simple nginx proxy.  I also added in forcing to https and some other things while I had the proxy, something of the form:

```
server {
  listen       443;
  server_name  foo.bar;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  # Redirect (*).foo.bar to (s3bucket)/(*)
  location / {
    index  index.html index.htm;

    set $legit "0";
    set $index "";

    # First off, we lose the index document functionality of S3 when we
    # proxy requests.  So we need to add that back on to our rewrites if
    # needed.  This is a little dangerous, probably should find a better
    # way if one exists.
    if ($uri ~* "\.foo\.bar$") {
      set $index "/index.html";
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\/$") {
      set $index "index.html";
    }

    # If we're making a request to foo.bar (not a sub-host),
    # make the request directly to "production"
    if ($host ~* "^foo\.bar") {
      set $legit "1";
      rewrite /(.*) /foo.bar/production/$1$index break;
    }

    # Otherwise, take the sub-host from the request and use that for the
    # redirect path
    if ($host ~* "^(.*?)\.foo\.bar") {
      set $legit "1";
      set $subhost $1;
      rewrite /(.*) /foo.bar/$subhost/$1$index break;
    }

    # Anything else, give them foo.bar
    if ($legit = "0") {
      return 302 https://foo.bar;
    }

    # Peform the actual proxy forward
    proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/;
    proxy_set_header Host s3.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_set_header Referer https://s3.amazonaws.com;

    proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    sub_filter google.com example.com;
    sub_filter_once off;
  }
}
```

This works - I go to a.foo.bar, and I get the index page I expect, and clicking around works.  However, part of the application also does an OAuth style login, and expects the browser to be redirected back to the page at /reentry?token=foo...  The problem is that path only exists as a route in the React app, and that app isn't loaded by a static web server like S3, so you just get a 404 (or 403 because I don't have an error page defined or forwarded yet).

So....  All that for the question...

Can I serve a ReactJS application from a dumb/static server like S3, and have it understand callbacks to it's routes?  Keep in mind that the index/error directives in S3 seem to be discarded when fronted with a proxy the way I have above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there was a lot in my original question, but the core of it really came down to: as a non-UI person, how do I make an OAuth workflow work with a React app?  The callback URL in this case is a route, which doesn't exist if you unload the index.html page.  If you're going directly against S3, this is solved by directing all errors to index.html, which reloads the routes and the callback works.

When fronted by nginx however, we lose this error->index.html routing.  Fortunately, it's a pretty simple thing to add back:

```
  location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 400 403 404 500 =200 /index.html;
```

Probably don't need all of those status codes - for S3, the big thing is the 403.  When you request a page that doesn't exist, it will treat it as though you're trying to browse the bucket, and give you back a 403 forbidden rather than a 404 not found or something like that.  So in this case a response from S3 that results in a 403 will get redirected to /index.html, which will recall the routes loaded there and the callback to /callback?token=... will work.